# Postgres sql throwing error on JOIN and Groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, inner-join

**BACKGROUND**

I am looking to join two tables together ('customers', 'orders') but am having a hard time with GROUP BY. I believe this is due to using Postgres but am unsure as I am relatively new to SQL.

**SOURCE CODE**

TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers
  (first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES
  ('Boy', 'George', 'george@gmail.com'),
  ('George', 'Michael', 'gm@gmail.com'),
  ('David', 'Bowie', 'david@gmail.com'),
  ('Blue', 'Steele', 'blue@gmail.com'),
  ('Bette', 'Davis', 'bette@aol.com');
  
  
  
  
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  order_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
  customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
);

INSERT INTO orders
  (order_date, amount, customer_id)
VALUES
  ('2/10/15', 99.99, 1),
  ('11/11/17', 35.5, 1),
  ('12/12/14', 800.67, 2),
  ('1/3/15', 12.5, 2),
  ('4/11/99', 450.24, 5);
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       order_date,
       Sum(amount) AS total_spent
FROM   customers
       JOIN orders
         ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP  BY orders.customer_id
ORDER  BY total_spent DESC;
```

**ERROR**

Query Error:

> error: column "customers.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*

Comment: error message is clear , show us your desired output

Comment: Put everything needed to ask in your post as text with the rest of a [mre]. [ask] But research before considering asking. This is clearly a faq, google your error message without your particular strings. Also read the manual for functionality you are using.

Comment: When using aggregate functions, anything NOT being aggregated must be in the group by.  Some engines may allow you to get away without putting elements in the group by such as MySQL but this can cause some strange behavior.  So simply put.  Anything in the select not being aggregated, include in the group by.  `GROUP  BY orders.customer_id,first_name,
       last_name,
       order_date`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select first_name,last_name,t1.total_spent from
customers join 
(SELECT customer_id,
       Sum(amount) AS total_spent
FROM   orders
GROUP  BY orders.customer_id) as t1
on t1.customer_id = customers.id
ORDER  BY total_spent DESC;
```

When you use an aggregate function `sum()`, `min()`, `max()` etc. any other fields must be in the `group by` clause. You don't want to group by `order_date` as at that point you might as well do a simple select.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the total *per customer*, then you don't want the date in the `SELECT` list.  This would normally be written as:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, sum(o.amount) AS total_spent
FROM customers c JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name
ORDER  BY total_spent DESC;
```

Note the use of table aliases which make the query easier to write and read.  Also, all the columns as *qualified*, indicating what table they come from.  Finally, the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` columns are consistent.

If `customers(id)` is the primary key, then you can also use:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, sum(o.amount) AS total_spent
FROM customers c JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total_spent DESC;
```

This is a special case where the `GROUP BY` columns and `SELECT` columns *are not consistent*.  However, this is allowed because the `GROUP BY` is by the *primary key* of the table and the other unaggregated columns are from the same table.